# What is the proper procedure for working with multiple channels in netty?

Tags: java, udp, netty

I have a UDP Multicast application which will be hardcoded to listen to specific groups of multicasts addresses. However, while I am able to have one NioDatagramChannel that joins multiple groups, my code cannot handle multiple NioDatagramChannels that listens to separate groups (somewhat like Java NIO selector). The following is the code I wrote:

```
public class NettyTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new NettyTest().run();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MulticastHandler handler = new MulticastHandler();
        MulticastHandler handler2 = new MulticastHandler();
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try{
            UDPChannel channel = new UDPChannel(5555, "eth0", "239.1.1.1");
            UDPChannel channel2 = new UDPChannel(5556, "eth0", "225.1.1.1");

            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ni)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1500 * 200)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioDatagramChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(NioDatagramChannel nioDatagramChannel) throws Exception {
                            nioDatagramChannel.pipeline().addLast(new MulticastHandler());  //<------------- modification
                        }
                    });

            System.out.println(channel.getMULTICAST_STRING()+" "+channel2.getMULTICAST_STRING());

            AttributeKey<String> markerKey = AttributeKey.valueOf("Marker");
            NioDatagramChannel ch = (NioDatagramChannel)b.bind(5555).sync().channel();
            ch.attr(markerKey).set(channel.getMULTICAST_STRING());
            ch.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress("239.1.1.1", 5555), ni).sync();
            group.register(ch);

            NioDatagramChannel ch1 =(NioDatagramChannel)b.bind(5556).sync().channel();
            ch1.attr(markerKey).set(channel2.getMULTICAST_STRING());
            ch1.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress("225.1.1.1", 5556), ni).sync();
            group.register(ch1);

//            ch.closeFuture().await();
//            ch1.closeFuture().await();
            ch.closeFuture();
            ch1.closeFuture();
        } catch (InterruptedException | SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MulticastHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket>{
    private MoldUdpHeader moldUdpHeader = new MoldUdpHeader();
    AttributeKey<String> markerKey = AttributeKey.valueOf("Marker");
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, DatagramPacket datagramPacket) throws Exception {
        moldUdpHeader.decode(datagramPacket.content().nioBuffer(), 0);
        System.out.println(channelHandlerContext.channel().attr(markerKey).get()+" "+moldUdpHeader.getSeqNum());
    }
}
```

I have tried the above but it gives a `io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.ensureOpen(ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source)`. What is the proper way to be able to process both of these channels? I do not want to combine both into one channel, because the messages on both channels can have same ID but different values (values are specific for that channel).

Edit: I just found out that either Netty or Log4j (i m not sure which) has been suppressing the console output for the errors that has happened with the sample code above. I found an inconspicuous log file which contains all the error messages Netty has been writing, even though the above does not use loggers at all. The following is the error logs. I have checked up some of the errors and modified my code above (it turns out each channel needs a new handle)

```
2023-03-15 13:56:50,688 WARN  method: [main] bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap (AbstractBootstrap.java:467) - Failed to set channel option 'IP_MULTICAST_IF' with value 'name:eth0 (eth0)' for channel '[id: 0xf46f62a3]'
io.netty.channel.ChannelException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setOption0(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:206) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setNetworkInterface(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:161) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.DefaultDatagramChannelConfig.setOption(DefaultDatagramChannelConfig.java:126) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setOption(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:216) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.setChannelOption(AbstractBootstrap.java:463) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.setChannelOptions(AbstractBootstrap.java:455) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:264) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:311) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.doBind(AbstractBootstrap.java:272) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:268) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:246) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at udp.NettyTest.run(NettyTest.java:52) ~[classes/:?]
    at udp.NettyTest.main(NettyTest.java:24) ~[classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setOption0(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:204) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No such file or directory
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.setInterface6(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.setOption(DatagramChannelImpl.java:226) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.setOption(DatagramChannelImpl.java:42) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setOption0(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:204) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    ... 12 more
2023-03-15 13:56:50,733 WARN  method: [main] bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap (AbstractBootstrap.java:467) - Failed to set channel option 'IP_MULTICAST_IF' with value 'name:eth0 (eth0)' for channel '[id: 0x5085932f]'
io.netty.channel.ChannelException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setOption0(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:206) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setNetworkInterface(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:161) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.DefaultDatagramChannelConfig.setOption(DefaultDatagramChannelConfig.java:126) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setOption(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:216) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.setChannelOption(AbstractBootstrap.java:463) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.setChannelOptions(AbstractBootstrap.java:455) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:264) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:311) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.doBind(AbstractBootstrap.java:272) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:268) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:246) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    at udp.NettyTest.run(NettyTest.java:57) ~[classes/:?]
    at udp.NettyTest.main(NettyTest.java:24) ~[classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setOption0(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:204) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No such file or directory
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.setInterface6(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.setOption(DatagramChannelImpl.java:226) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.setOption(DatagramChannelImpl.java:42) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_351]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannelConfig.setOption0(NioDatagramChannelConfig.java:204) ~[netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:4.1.78.Final]
    ... 12 more
```

It looks like it now receives both channels packets, so thats pretty great.

output:

```
239.1.1.1 225.1.1.1
239.1.1.1 0
225.1.1.1 0
225.1.1.1 1
239.1.1.1 1
225.1.1.1 2
239.1.1.1 2
225.1.1.1 3
239.1.1.1 3
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that framework, but you give the port 5555 **two** times for each channel and additionally a bind() function usually binds a local socket to listen. I would guess, by using bind() you force the system to use the same local port twice, which does not work.

Try using different port numbers in the bind() call and I **think** you could succeed.

Comment: In NIO, this should be fine because I am using the reuse_address option. I did however try to use different port numbers, however it only listens to the first channel regardless